# If post by specific role different css to everyone

Tags: css, user-roles

So i have searched alot but cant find a solution.
Every solution which i find is changing css only to that specific role not for everyone else.
Basicly i want to do this:

```
If user role contributor then do this to his post and also so everyone can see it
.type-post { border: 10px solid #fff }
else
.type-post { border: 20px solid #000 }
```

So if a post i made by a specific user who has user role contributor his post borders color will be white and 10 px and everyone should see that not only people with that user role.
If post is made by everyone one else it should have default css or a css of my pick and everyone should see that including people with user role contributor.
Hope someone can help me out!

Comment: this can't be done with just CSS, the role of the author isn't present in the HTML markup by default, PHP code is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the post classes depending on user role to include an additional selector which add your custom styling i.e

```
function add_contributor_class_to_single_post( $classes ) { 

    if ( is_single() ) {
        $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
        $author_ID = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
        $author_data = get_userdata( $author_ID );
        if (in_array( 'contributor', $author_data->roles)) {
            // add post class
            array_push( $classes, 'user-contributor' );
        }
    }
    return $classes;    

}   
add_filter( 'post_class', 'add_contributor_class_to_single_post' );
```

Then update your css to:

```
.type-post.user-contributor { border: 10px solid #fff }
.type-post { border: 20px solid #000 }
```

Comment: "// add post class"  what should i write there? Cause right now my site crashes with your code.

Comment: sorry a semi-colon was missing.

Comment: I get no errors but cant see any changes with css i wrote !important at the end also.

Comment: Now it works you misspeled "contributer" it should be "contributor"

Comment: Hi man! Your code works perfect on every page expect on pages "is_category()" or "is_archive()" Do you have a fix for it? Here is some explanation why it doesn't work on those pages https://wordpress.org/support/topic/if-category-2/

Comment: those pages do not have an author, you'll have to update your post for/while loop and add the conditional formatting logic.

Comment: if you can share with me the code from your index.php i'll be able to help more ( specifically the while/for loop of posts )

Comment: archive.php https://pastebin.com/mcWVVrqX and index.php https://pastebin.com/Abtfxyuu

Comment: Thanks, its uses a partial tempalte located in "template-parts/content" to render the post cards. can you share that with me as this is where the html is stored

Comment: I use this theme: https://wordpress.org/themes/treville/ the file it uses i think is called "content-excerpt.php"

Comment: cool will have a look

Comment: try this, https://pastebin.com/gK8tZ86r, in template-parts/content-page.php

Comment: Tested your code it was wrong file. But i took some parts from your code and added to archive.php which is the correct file and its that file which should be manipulated. And it works but now the page looks wierd. I think i can take it from here but if you have time can u check archive.php cause its that file which should be manipulated. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Thanks for your help it works pretty good now some css issues but i can take it from here now. Correct file was archive.php Super thanks for the help!